# How (if at all) does Windows 7 incremental backup utility handle drive failure?

Tags: windows-7, backup

I want to use the Windows 7 incremental backup utility to regularly backup files from three old smaller drives to a new big drive.
What will happen if one of the old drives starts failing? Imagine a file on the old drive gets corrupted. Will this corruption propagate to the backup?

Comment: HDD corruption gets handled behind the scenes by the HDD controller. When it's sent to retrieve a file and finds corruption, it will try to copy the corrupted file to another area. But I don't believe there's a guarantee that the copy will match the uncorrupted original, and I don't think the OS is made aware of the potential problem. I suspect that Win 7 backup will back it up if that is called for. A partial safeguard is to have two generations of backup. Backup the backup file, then backup the active file. If you discover the corruption quickly, you will still have a good backup available.

Comment: Hmm I was worried that that's what might happen. I think enabling file history on the backup drive might help add this exact redundancy.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/doxley/2008/10/29/self-healing-ntfs/